# Run a node.js server on Azure not getting response

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure

I've followed this tutorial : ( https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-nodejs-develop-deploy-mac/ ) for run a node.js on azure. But **I'm not getting the response my node server**, it show only blank page.

It works when run locally and when I deployed is no error, just not get response.

this is my server.js code :

```
var http = require('https');
var port = process.env.port || 1337;
http.createServer(function(req, res){
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/plain'});
    res.end('TEST Azure\n');
}).listen(port);
```

And in client side, how to code it for receive the response?

Thank you.

Comment: Just type `https://<azure-public-ip>:1337` in a browser and you should see "TEST Azure"

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused by using `require(https)`. The correct way is code `require(http)`. Please see the tutorial https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-nodejs-develop-deploy-mac/#build-and-test-your-application-locally and pay attention to the code, see the picture below:

[image]

And in the browser client, you can receive the response for addressing `http://<your-webapp-name>.azurewebsites.net/` or `https://<your-webapp-name>.azurewebsites.net/`.

Azure WebApp is hosting node.js applications in IIS on Windows for Azure. Azure WebApp only support the port 80 & 443 for accessing in IIS. And IIS connect the NodeJS Application thru iisnode (https://github.com/Azure/iisnode).

Comment: Thank you. I change it to require('http'), but it still not work.

Comment: @PiyanuchSinwasanamongkol Could you supply more details for helping resolve your issue? I used the same code as yours, and it works fine. So I need to know what you do for creating Azure WebApp and deploying the Node code.

Comment: I followed this website ( https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-nodejs-develop-deploy-mac/#build-and-test-your-application-locally ). 
And this is my website (http://testwebrtc.azurewebsites.net/). "Test" that show on the screen is my index.html.